# Combined inheritance, implementation and generics issue

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, implementation

In example below I want to create multiple types of Puppies inherited from `PuppyBase` base class that implements `IPuppy` generic interface. `Bark` method impemented in base class, the others - in derived `CutePuppy` class.

I can't get how can I create another puppy here who wants another feed and barks differently?

```
public interface IPuppy<TBark, TDesiredFood>
{
    void Bark(TBark sound);
    Task<TDesiredFood> Sleep();
    Task Eat(TDesiredFood food);
}

public abstract class PuppyBase:IPuppy<Yap,Sausage>
{
    public void Bark(Yap sound)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sound.ToString());
    }

    public abstract Task<Sausage> Sleep();
    public abstract Task Eat(Sausage food);
}

class CutePuppy : PuppyBase
{
    public override Task<Sausage> Sleep()
    {
        // Implementation
        // ...
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Task Eat(Sausage food)
    {
        // Implementation
        // ...
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just make it implement another variant of the `IPuppy` interface. It's just fine to have `IPuppy<Yap, Sausage>, IPuppy<Breek, Carmala>` (though `Sleep` has to be an explicit implementation, since the C# compiler doesn't allow return type overloads). That said, samples like this are always weird. For example, you're probably not going to have different implementations of `Eat` for different foods - and you're not going to explicitly cast `PuppyBase` to `IPuppy<Yap, Carrot>` when you want to feed it a carrot, are you? :P

Comment: To solve your "Combined inheritance, implementation and generics issue", don't use inheritance. Just have your classes implement the interface directly and use composition when you have replicated functionality.

Comment: @Luaan, you're right. It's weird in this example, but in real code I really need defferent implementations of some methods. Meanwhile some of methods are always the same, that's why I decided to use a Base Class. David Arno, I'll give it a try, tnx.

Comment: I've started using extension methods instead of base classes for things like that, and they work great. The thing is, class inheritance (especially without multiple inheritance) actually isn't all that good of an abstraction - it only really works for simple tree hierarchies. I've noticed that when working with any kind of complex inheritance-oriented code, you'll spend a huge amount of time figuring out how to warp the hiearchy to accomodate new types (look how fragile and rigid GUI type hierarchies are, for example). Of course, composition has issues of its own, there's no silver bullet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to specify generic types on base class you may make it also generic

```
public abstract class PuppyBase<TBark, TDesiredFood> : IPuppy<TBark, TDesiredFood>
    where TBark : ISound
{
    public void Bark(TBark sound)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sound.ToString());
    }

    public abstract Task<TDesiredFood> Sleep();
    public abstract Task Eat(TDesiredFood food);
}

public interface ISound
{
    string ToString();
}
```

This way for CutePuppy you should

```
class CutePuppy : PuppyBase<Yap,Sausage>
```

for NotSoNicePuppy

```
class NotSoNicePuppy: PuppyBase<Wow,Human>
```